# Django: Validate uniqueness of user uploaded files with hashes

Tags: python, django, validation, modelform

I am trying to find an elegant solution to check whether an user uploaded file already exists.

1. A user uploads a file using a **SubmissionForm**, which just includes the file field of the **Submission** class.
2. This form should compute the hash for the file, add it to the **Submission** instance, and compute validation checks there.
3. If the uniqueness constraint on the hash value is violated, this should raise a validation error using the *duplicate* code, so that the form can print an adequate error message.

The relevant files:

```py
# models.py
class Submission(models.Model):
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    file_sha1 = models.CharField(max_length=40, editable=False, unique=True)
    file = models.FileField(
        upload_to=<... file saving ...>,
        validators=[
            <... validators ...>
        ],
    )
```

```py
# forms.py
class SubmissionForm(forms.models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Submission
        fields = ("file",)
        widget = {"file": forms.FileField()}
        error_messages = {
            "file": {
                <...error message codes + messages...>,
                "duplicate": DUPLICATE_ERROR,
            }
        }

    def save(self, exercise):
        self.instance.exercise = exercise
        return super().save()
```

In addition, I have a `_generate_sha1(file)` method hashing a file. I saw couple of solutions to this problem using validation in `views.py` but I believe that is not the right place for it. I looked into `clean()` and `clean_file()` but I did not manage to get it working.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you do store the hash of the file in the field `file_sha1 ` then why not check that for a scanned document if the hash exists or not?

Comment: I do not know where to do it. The file comes in and I need to generate the hash somewhere, and do that before normal validation. I do not understand where people normally this kind of "preprocessing" and custom validation. All the methods like clean() have purposes on their own which I would overwrite when defining them.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but I was looking for something similar myself.

I've implemented the checking logic in my form's `clean()` method.
Note I'm manually opening (and closing, if needed) the file as the model's `save()` method still needs to access it.

Models:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/",)
    image_sha1 = models.CharField(max_length=40, editable=False, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Calculate the SHA-1 hash of the uploaded file and store to DB.
        sha1_hash = hashlib.sha1()
        with self.image.open("rb") as f:
            # Read and update hash string value in blocks of 4K
            for byte_block in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
                sha1_hash.update(byte_block)
            self.image_sha1 = sha1_hash.hexdigest()

            super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Forms:

```
class CreateImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image', )

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(CreateImageForm, self).clean()

        uploaded_image = cleaned_data.get('image', None)

        sha1_hash = hashlib.sha1()
        # Not using 'with' to open/close the file, as we need to access it in the model's save() function.
        # Instead, manually opening and closing the file (in case of error).
        f = uploaded_image.open("rb")
        # Read and update hash string value in blocks of 4K
        for byte_block in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
            sha1_hash.update(byte_block)

        # Check if we already have a patient with the same name/dob
        existing_image = Image.objects.filter(image_sha1=sha1_hash.hexdigest())
        if existing_image:
            f.close()
            raise ValidationError(
                mark_safe("This image had been uploaded before: '<a href='{0}'>{1}</a>'."
                          .format(reverse('image_view', args=(existing_image[0].id,)), existing_image[0]))
                          )

        return cleaned_data
```